# I get an error when I want to use EDM Codes in my Windows forms

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, visual-studio

I wanted to try code a program which I wanted to use EDM in my codes and in my Visual Studio. I coded everything (even `Save` button and etc) but there is a problem that whenever I want to delete a record from my database (which is on my computer in SQL Server 2014), I get an error and my program suddenly crashes and I don't know why. Can you tell me what can I do to solve this problem? Thanks in advance for your helpful answers.

Here is my code:

```
 private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        if (txtCode.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("code morede nazar ra vared konid");
            txtCode.Focus();
            return;
        }

        tblfastfood1 w1 = FA.tblfastfood1.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Code == Convert.ToInt32(txtCode.Text));

        if (w1 == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("chenin codi mojod nist");
            txtCode.Focus();
            return;
        }

        w1.Esm = txtEsmMoshtari.Text;
        w1.Address = txtAddress.Text;
        w1.GhazaAsli = comboBox1.Text;
        w1.Noshidani = comboBox2.Text;
        w1.Salad = comboBox3.Text;

        FA.SaveChanges();

        dataGridView1.DataSource = FA.tblfastfood1.ToList();
    }
```

Here is the error I get:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can't be translated to SQL, so it can't be used in your LINQ provider (probably LINQ to Entities):

```
Convert.ToInt32(txtCode.Text)
```

Instead of using it in the expression directly, perform this operation before the LINQ expression and use the resulting value (which *can* be passed to SQL):

```
int code = Convert.ToInt32(txtCode.Text);
tblfastfood1 w1 = FA.tblfastfood1.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Code == code);
```